# A way to see the original question/answer if it was edited on SE app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I often see edited question/answer while surfing around the SE sites on the app on my phone. Sometimes I wish to see the original post but on the app this seems impossible.

To do this now I have to open the question/answer in my browser which takes time and data

How can I do this? Can this feature be added to the SE app?

Comment: Meanwhile, the only alternative is to open the question in browser (Select "... More" on the question and then "Open in browser"), there you can see the revision history by tapping the "Edited" link.

Comment: @Andrew T. I must have missed that one...